# problem with "playsound" library when using "tkinter" for a vocabulary trainer

Tags: python, tkinter, playsound

I have programmed a code for a vocabulary trainer which works without problems from the terminal window. Now I wanted to create a nicer GUI by using tkinter. I face now, however, the problem that after exactly 2 vocabulary, playsound does not work anymore. Funnily enough, I have tried to eliminate the "root.after()" method, then exactly after 3 vocabular playsound does not work anymore. Any idea what could be the reason for this problem.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def question7_hr(path_random_exercise_hr, current_textfile_hr, path_random_exercise_de, current_textfile_de, plus_minus_score, weights, index_random_exercise, random_exercise, counter_correct, counter_incorrect):
    # Display the text at the top of the screen
    text_label = Label(root, text=current_textfile_hr, font=("Helvetica", 18), fg="red")
    text_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, anchor="center")
    plus_minus_score_label = Label(root, text="plus-minus-score: " + str(plus_minus_score), font=("Helvetica", 14), fg="blue")
    plus_minus_score_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.20, anchor="center")


    root.after(200, lambda: playsound(path_random_exercise_hr))

    # Wait until translation is called for
    translation7 = BooleanVar()
    translation7_button = Radiobutton(root, text="See translation now", variable=translation7, value=True)
    translation7_button.config(indicatoron=0, width=15, height=2)

    translation7_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.27, anchor="center")

    # Wait for the user to select Yes or No
    root.wait_variable(translation7)

    translation_shown = False

    if translation7.get():
        # If Yes is selected, display the translated text
        translation_label = Label(root, text=current_textfile_de, font=("Helvetica", 18), fg="red")
        translation_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor="center")
        translation_shown = True
        root.after(200, lambda: playsound(path_random_exercise_de))

        # Ask if the translation was correct
        question8 = Label(root, text="Have you translated the text correctly?", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        question8.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.45, anchor="center")

        # Create the Yes and No buttons for the translation question
        var8 = BooleanVar()
        yes8_button = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var8, value=True)
        no8_button = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var8, value=False)
        yes8_button.config(indicatoron=0, width=10, height=2)
        no8_button.config(indicatoron=0, width=10, height=2)
        yes8_button.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.52, anchor="center")
        no8_button.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.52, anchor="center")

        # Wait for the user to select Yes or No for the translation question
        root.wait_variable(var8)

        # Return the answer to the translation question
        correct_answer = "y" if var8.get() else "n"

        if correct_answer == "y":
            counter_correct += 1
            weights[index_random_exercise] = int(max(1, weights[index_random_exercise] / 2))
            plus_minus_score = -int(math.log2(weights[index_random_exercise])) + 10
            weights_hr = [list(map(str, weights))]
            history_current_example = [today, random_exercise[0][1], current_textfile_hr, correct_answer]
            history_hr.append(history_current_example)
        elif correct_answer == "n":
            counter_incorrect +=1
            weights[index_random_exercise] = weights[index_random_exercise] * 2
            plus_minus_score = -int(math.log2(weights[index_random_exercise])) + 10
            weights_hr = [list(map(str, weights))]
            history_current_example = [today, random_exercise[0][1], current_textfile_hr, correct_answer]
            history_hr.append(history_current_example)
        new_plus_minus_score_label = Label(root, text="The new plus-minus-score is: " + str(plus_minus_score), font=("Helvetica", 14),
                                       fg="blue")
        new_plus_minus_score_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.60, anchor="center")

        # Ask if the user wants to continue
        question9 = Label(root, text="Do you want to continue?", font=("Helvetica", 14))
        question9.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor="center")

        # Create the Yes and No buttons for continuation
        var9 = BooleanVar()
        yes9_button = Radiobutton(root, text="Yes", variable=var9, value=True)
        no9_button = Radiobutton(root, text="No", variable=var9, value=False)
        yes9_button.config(indicatoron=0, width=10, height=2)
        no9_button.config(indicatoron=0, width=10, height=2)
        yes9_button.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.82, anchor="center")
        no9_button.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.82, anchor="center")

        # Wait for the user to select Yes or No for continuation
        root.wait_variable(var9)

        text_label.destroy()
        plus_minus_score_label.destroy()
        translation7_button.destroy()
        translation_label.destroy()
        question8.destroy()
        yes8_button.destroy()
        no8_button.destroy()
        new_plus_minus_score_label.destroy()
        question9.destroy()
        yes9_button.destroy()
        no9_button.destroy()

        # Return the answer regarding continuation
        decision_continuation = "y" if var9.get() else "n"
```